# JavaFX: how to choose tile and add a number & border line?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am a beginner and I want to make a *Sudoku* game. I created my **9x9** grid in `private Parent createContent()` but I do not know how to make the bolded lines between the blocks.  I also try to click and highlight one cell then press one key and add the number to it.

---

Here is what I've done so far:

```
public class TestJAVAfx extends Application {
         /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        private Parent createContent(){
            Pane root = new Pane();
            root.setPrefSize(541,700);

            for(int i = 0 ; i<9; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                    Tile tile = new Tile();
                    tile.setTranslateX(j*60);
                    tile.setTranslateY(i*60);

                    root.getChildren().addAll(tile);
                }
            }

            return root;
        }
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene (createContent ()));
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public  class Tile extends StackPane{

            private Text text = new Text();

            public Tile(){
                Rectangle border = new Rectangle(60,60);
                border.setFill(null);
                border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                getChildren().addAll(border,text);


                setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                    if(e.getButton()== MouseButton.PRIMARY){
                        getKey();
                    }
                });



            }

            private Text getKey(){
                Text key = new Text();

                setOnKeyPressed(e->{
                    KeyCode keyCode = e.getCode();
                    if(keyCode.equals(KeyCode.A)){
                        drawONE();
                    }
                });


                return key;
            }

            private void drawONE(){
                text.setText("1");
            }
            private void drawTWO(){
                text.setText("2");
            }
            private void drawTHREE(){
                text.setText("3");
            }
            private void drawFOUR(){
                text.setText("4");
            }
            private void drawFIVE(){
                text.setText("5");
            }
            private void drawSIX(){
                text.setText("6");
            }
            private void drawSEVEN(){
                text.setText("7");
            }
            private void drawEIGHT(){
                text.setText("8");
            }
            private void drawNINE(){
                text.setText("9");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by bold lines between the blocks. To make the lines bold you can set the strokewidth to 2. To highlight a particular tile, you can keep a reference to it and apply the styles when one is selected. This way you will also have a reference to the tile to update with text.

Below is the modified code of your demo. This should give you some basic idea about how to proceed with.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestJAVAfx extends Application {

    private ObjectProperty<Tile> focusedTile = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(542, 542);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                Tile tile = new Tile();
                tile.setTranslateX(j * 60);
                tile.setTranslateY(i * 60);
                root.getChildren().addAll(tile);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        focusedTile.addListener((obs, oldTile, tile) -> {
            if (oldTile != null) {
                oldTile.getBorderRectangle().setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            }
            if (tile != null) {
                tile.getBorderRectangle().setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
                tile.toFront();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
            if (focusedTile.get() != null) {
                if (Character.isDigit(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))) {
                    focusedTile.get().getText().setText(e.getCharacter());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class Tile extends StackPane {
        private Text text = new Text();
        private Rectangle borderRectangle;

        public Tile() {
            borderRectangle = new Rectangle(60, 60);
            borderRectangle.setFill(null);
            borderRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            borderRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(borderRectangle, text);
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    focusedTile.set(this);
                }
            });
        }

        public Rectangle getBorderRectangle() {
            return borderRectangle;
        }

        public Text getText() {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```